# show delete button on specific user who logged in

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I am trying that the user who is logged in can delete his own posts so only he should see the delete button on his posts. I was thinking by my own that I had to bind the user who is logged in to the posts/img ID and then he should see the button. I'm struggling with this a bit so every useful comment is appreciated!

**PHP**

```
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT users.user_id, users.username,
                                picas.img_id, picas.user_id, picas.name, picas.description, picas.created_at
                          FROM users
                          JOIN picas ON users.user_id = picas.user_id
                          ORDER BY picas.created_at DESC");


while($pica = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$ses_user = $_SESSION['username'];

echo '<div class="image_post">';

if(isset($ses_user) == $pica['user_id'] && $pica['img_id']) {
  echo '<form action="logic/delete_post.php?id='.$pica['img_id'].'" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="?id='.$pica['img_id'].'" />
          <input type="submit" name="deleteSubmit" value="Delete" class="delete_post" />
        </form>';
}


    echo '<div class="user_avatar"><img src="avatars/'.$pica['username'].'.jpeg" /></div>
                <div class="user_name">'.$pica['username'].'</div> <br><br><br><br>
                <div class="timeago">'.$diff.'</div>
                <div class="image_description">'.$pica['description'].'</div>
                <img src="'.$pica['name'].'" />

          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>';

}

?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't add ?id... to the form action if you use POST method.
Also the hidden field should read <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$pica['img_id'].'"/>.
Finally if you want to check only the owner the && part of the if clause is useless

Comment: The if statement is wrong. I want that the form is shown only what the user posted by himself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are checking `isset($ses_user) == $pica['user_id']` being [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) a function that returns a `bool`.

What you want to check is if the current user is the owner.

The correct condition should be:

```
...

if(isset($ses_user) && ($ses_user == $pica['username']) && $pica['img_id']) {
echo '<form action="logic/delete_post.php?id='.$pica['img_id'].'" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="?id='.$pica['img_id'].'" />
      <input type="submit" name="deleteSubmit" value="Delete" class="delete_post" />
    </form>';
}
...
```